# The number of combinations of Fi to F255 that satisfies the following inequality.

Tags: summation, combinations, information-theory

Consider the following equation:

$H(x) = - \sum_{i=0}^{255} P_{i} \ \log_{2} \ (P_{i}) $

When $ P_{0} = P_{1} = ... =P_{255} = \frac {1}{256}$

$H(x) = - \sum_{i=0}^{255} \frac {1}{256} \ \log_{2} \ (\frac {1}{256}) = 8 $

Where $p_i$ is the probability of the character $x_i$ to occur in the file.

The file Size is 256 characters.

We will refer to the frequency of the character $x_i$ as $f_i$. ($p_i$ = $f_i / 256)$.

The sum of the frequencies of the characters will always be $256$.

My question is:

Given that $H(x)$ is $\ge 7$, How to calculate the number of possible combinations of characters frequencies (from $f_{0}$ to $f_{255}$) that makes the inequality true?

Comment: Better if you can write out the equation. The help menu has instructions for formatting mathematics here.

Comment: This seems difficult. Could you give us some context how you encountered this problem? Do you have reason to believe that there's a solution in closed form?

Comment: What inequality are you talking about?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done it.

Comment: @joriki I encountered this problem while I was thinking about the entropy of data and information theory, it is not in a textbook, I was wondering how many files of size 256 bytes and has a data entropy of 7 or higher, or in general how to calculate the number of files with an entropy ranging between 2 values. Can you explain what do mean by "a solution in closed form"?

Comment: @Ali $H(x) \ge 7$ The equation that defines H(x) is shown above.

Comment: I was using "a solution in closed form" in the vague way it's often used, meaning "something that can be written down as a formula using mostly elementary operations and functions". This could also include an infinite series or the like. What it's mainly meant not to include is a solution in the form of a computer program that spits out the number. This is what I believe will likely be required to answer this question.

Comment: Note that you can get proper formatting for operations like $\log$ by using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: There are probably some good estimates in the information theory literature, but I doubt there's a better way to find an exact answer than to have a computer run through all the possibilities.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree with you both... I have even tried to solve it using Microsoft excel by trying all possible solutions manually but I thought that will be hard and it will take quite long, so I came here to see if someone has a better method or if it can be solved using some mathematical formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you know any program I can use to approach this problem?

Comment: I might code it up tomorrow if I find the time. How do you want to count the combinations? Do you want the characters treated as distinguishable, i.e. is $200$ ones and $56$ twos the same combination as $200$ twos and $56$ ones, or to be counted separately?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a programmer. You might consider posting to a coding site. But do you really need to know the exact number?

Comment: @joriki If you find time please count both combinations and permutations. The combinations is when 200 ones and 56 twos are the same as 200 twos and 56 ones. The permutations is when the characters are treated as distinguishable. And thanks in advance.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I need to know it in order to find out if my idea is going to work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

\begin{eqnarray*}
H&=&-\sum_ip_i\log_2p_i\\
&=&
-\sum_i\frac{f_i}{256}\log_2\frac{f_i}{256}\\
&=&-\frac1{256}\sum_i\left(f_i\log_2f_i-f_i\log_2256\right)\\
&=&8-\frac1{256}\sum_if_i\log_2f_i\\
&\ge&7
\end{eqnarray*}

and thus

$$
\sum_if_i\log_2f_i\le256\;,
$$

or (with $0^0=1$)

$$
\prod_if_i^{f_i}\le2^{256}\;,
$$

which is a good form of the condition for computer purposes, as it allows us to do everything with integer computations without rounding errors.

[This Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/f7c0db310358b6d7fa3a4ff37e66e686) performs the computation.

The number of admissible frequency assignments with the characters treated as indistinguishable is $83497348$.

The number of admissible frequency assignments with the characters treated as distinguishable is

> 24377117336293373068077194760018608890164075844989457788709896790123975565346885123594568979784410896832589991747589003175962663714550060904409876659.

The number of admissible files is

> 32294749681296695275407031178128991719155449234352428397819516042408274669320014204971984810980113839713404991542286248511856534533725621770720443204257942757841685726869445418911988343694467610597716668644890003072566046313323943032907344235616323318993946853455308766090267464412982787428679760943574604833815718162734374857821826072728560557821111484218984087078219375690986647992988689743586158787866836166182263828747140499381872352135857955196142673766290736723267626340276801993482047192554123014017270771149942354934825395952764480929741003537616825060105246264524800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

There are $256^{256}$ files in total, so approximately $99.93\%$ of the files fulfil the condition.

The results should be reasonably reliable, as the total number of files is correctly reproduced when the entropy condition is omitted, and this depends on all three counts being performed correctly.

Here's a $\log_2$-plot of the proportion of files with $n$ characters chosen from $n$ symbols for which

$$
\prod_if_i^{f_i}\gt2^n\;,
$$

that is, the proportion of inadmissible files. The line is a linear fit to the last $40$ data points, with slope approximately $-0.0317$. I don't know how this constant could be calculated. Note the interesting odd/even structure. (Click on the image to see the full high-resolution version.)

[image: log_2 plot of the proportion of inadmissible files]